# PHP Enter in File

Tags: php

I made an easy code in PHP where you have 3 textboxes where you put your name address and living place and it will save in a file called `name.txt`. Everything works fine, but I want to save it in the format below and not like this (Name Adrress Livingplace):

```
Name
Address
Living place

Name
etc.
```

I have tried to but /n into the fputs but it didnt work. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <?php
            if (!empty($_GET)) {            // -----
            $naamnieuw = $_GET["naam"]; // Naam word een variable.
            $adres = $_GET["adres"];
            $woon = $_GET["woon"];
            if (file_exists("naam.txt")) {      // Checkt of naam.txt bestaat
            $fp = fopen("naam.txt", "r+");  // Opent naam.txt om erin te kunne schrijven
            // $naam = fgets($fp);          // De variable naam leest de naam op uit het bestand naam.txt de variable fp verwijst weer naar fopen naam.txt en dat opent het weer zodat je ernaar kan schrijven.
            fclose($fp);                // Sluit het bestand
            $fp = fopen("naam.txt", "a");   // Hier word variable fp veranderd in het openen van naam.txt maar het maakt het bestand ook als het niet bestaat.
            // echo "Jouw naam is dus $naamnieuw";  // Zegt de naam van de textbox.
            // if ($naamnieuw != $naam) {           // Als de $naam in het bestand niet gelijk is aan de naam nieuw in het textbox dan zegt die dit.
            // echo "<br>maar de vorige keer heette je nog $naam";
            // }
            fputs($fp, $naamnieuw."\n");        // Schrijft de niewenaam naar het bestand
            fputs($fp, $adres."\n");
            fputs($fp, $woon."\n"."\n");
            fclose($fp);                    // Sluit het bestand
            // rewind($fp);
            }                       
            // else {                       
            // $fp = fopen("naam.txt", "w");        // Variable fp word nu veranderd in w dat zorgt ervoor dat je er naar kunt schrijven en als er al iets in staat dat het overwirte wordt.
            // $naamnieuw = $_GET["naam"];      // De naam in het textbox word een variable.
            // fputs($fp, $naamnieuw);          // Schrijft de naam naar het bestand.
            // fputs($fp, $adres);
            // fputs($fp, $woon);
            // fclose($fp);                 // Sluit het bestand
            // }                    
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="naamform" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
                Naam        <input type="text" name="naam"><br>
                Adres       <input type="text" name="adres"><br>
                Woonplaats  <input type="text" name="woon">
                <br>
                <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="opslaan">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Windows uses "\r\n" to signify line separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            fputs($fp, $naamnieuw."\r\n");        
            fputs($fp, $adres."\r\n");
            fputs($fp, $woon."\r\n"."\r\n");
```

This should do the trick.

I reformatted a bit of your code for readability:

```
          if(!empty($_GET)) {

                //Declareer variabeles
                $naamnieuw = $_GET["naam"];
                $adres = $_GET["adres"];
                $woon = $_GET["woon"];

                if(file_exists("naam.txt")) { 
                    $fp = fopen("naam.txt", "a");   
                    fputs($fp, $naamnieuw."\r\n");      
                    fputs($fp, $adres."\r\n");
                    fputs($fp, $woon."\r\n"."\r\n");
                    fclose($fp);
                } else {
                     $fp = fopen("naam.txt", "w");       
                     $naamnieuw = $_GET["naam"];     
                     fputs($fp, $naamnieuw."\r\n");    
                     fputs($fp, $adres."\r\n");
                     fputs($fp, $woon."\r\n"."\r\n");
                     fclose($fp); 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The "\n" in :

```
fputs($fp, $naamnieuw."\n");
```

is to be used on linux systems.

For Windows you can use "\r\n".

If you dont want to care about it, you should use :

```
fputs($fp, $naamnieuw . PHP_EOL);
```

It's the PHP end of line character :

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php